# Is it possible to use Google browser as an emulator for Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, android-emulator, flutter-web

Unfortunately, I have a weak 4 GB computer in RAM and a processor I5
I want to use Google Browser as an emulator instead of Android emulators because they are heavy on the computer

Flutter - Dart _ Android _ Vscode

Comment: You can run your code in Google chrome using the command: `flutter run -d chrome` but that will never be a substitute for an emulator. Try upgrading your RAM to min. 8GB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. But you need to enable web for your project. And you also will not able to be test the Android and iOS specific features. If you are planning to develop for mobile, you may not have support for various third party libraries as they may not have support for web.